# How to find Web Interface Port for Google Cloud VM cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc, ssh-tunnel, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to create an SSH tunnel to run Jupyter on a Google Cloud Dataproc cluster.

[The tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces#create_an_ssh_tunnel) gives the following template for creating the tunnel. It says:

"Replace port1 with the Cloud Shell port you will use (8080 - 8084), and port2 with the Web interface port on the cluster master node."

```
gcloud compute ssh master-host-name \
    --project=project-id --zone master-host-zone  -- \
    -4 -N -L port1:master-host-name:port2
```

What I am stuck on is port 2. I've looked in VPC settings, in the VM settings, etc but I cannot find any "web interface port". Is there someplace specific that I should be looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find this article helpful:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces

You're likely looking for Yarn resource manager on port `8088`. However, if you want to drill down into your applications (which do not run on master node) you may find setting up SSH tunnel easier to work with:

`gcloud compute ssh master-host-name ... -- -D 1080 -N`

Then start the browser pointed at the proxy:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome \
  --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:1080" \
  --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost" \
  --user-data-dir=/tmp/master-host-name
```

You can now enter `http://master-host-name:8088` in browser's address bar.